# Extract human name from his CV in Python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, data-science, spacy

As you all know names of persons normally on the top of their resume, so i did NER(name entity recognition) tagging using spaCy library on CV's and then i extract the first tag of **PERSON** (hoping it should be Human Name). Some time it works for me fine but some time it gives me Other things which are not names(because spaCy don't even recognize some names with any **NER** tag), so it is giving me some other things which it recognize as a **PERSON** it may be like 'Curriculam vitae' obviously this i don't want.
Following is a Code for which i was talking above...

```
import spacy
import docx2txt

nlp = spacy.load('en_default')
my_text = docx2txt.process("/home/waqar/CV data/Adnan.docx")
doc_2 = nlp(my_text)
for ent in doc_2.ents:
    if ent.label_ == "PERSON":
        print('{}'.format(ent))
        break
```

Is there any way through which i can add some name to NER for 'PERSON' tag in spaCy because then it will be able to recognize human names written in CV's
i think my logic is fine but something i am missing....
I would be very thankful if u peoples help me as i am Student and a beginer in python hope u peoples will definitely suggest some thing

```
OutPut

Abdul Ahad Ghous
```

but some time it giving me OutPuts like following as NER recognize it as a PERSON and don't even give any tag to the human name in this CV.

```
Curriculum Vitae
```

Comment: I think it will be difficult to guarantee that spacy will always find names since it is quite sensitive to the model's vocabulary. You could try using a bigger spacy model (https://spacy.io/usage/models), or you could also try looking for patterns by using the phrase matcher (https://spacy.io/usage/examples#section-information-extraction).

Comment: Dear @Waqar. did you find any solution? If you have please can you share your approach? thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'll encourage you to ask the question here in the discussion instead https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions. Most probably the questions would be flagged as "asking for tool/fix recommendation" as it is now.