# How can extract the exact human name from resume with spacy with patterns

Tags: python, spacy

I'm extracting the human name from the resume with the spacy model `en_core_web_sm` and using spacy patterns like that

```
PATTERN = [
    [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}],
    [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}],
    [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}],
    [{'POS': 'NOUN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}]
]
```

But With This working fine some and giving the exact name of the human but some time giving the wrong name like `curriculum vitae, from Resume Genius, Sr, Electrical Engineer`

```
matcher.add("NAME", PATTERN)
    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
    matches = matcher(nlp_text)

    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = nlp_text[start:end]
        return span.text
```

I'm getting `Name` like this but giving problems due to identifying the proper name. Please give me a solution. Thanks

Comment: How could you know that "Electrical Engineer" is not a proper name?

Comment: Can you please guide me about that. Because I'm using spacy patterns. With this sometimes gives proper human name but sometimes not giving proper human name. Thanks

Comment: Because resumes are bullet items and not complete sentences, there isn't enough context for it to tell the difference.  I'm not saying you can fix it, I'm saying it may not be fixable.  The applicant name is usually going to be topmost; perhaps you can use that as a clue.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to match human names with a pattern like this doesn't make any sense, this is not the right way to approach the problem.

If you want to get human names that's what the NER (Named Entity Recognition) component is for. You should use `doc.ents` and get all the entities with the label PERSON rather than using a pattern on part of speech types. See [the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities) for a usage example.

Comment: Thanks, Polm I used this functionality but gave the same results. Sometimes giving proper Name and sometimes giving randomly Name.

Comment: Dear @polm23 you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239206/extract-human-name-from-his-cv-in-python) is also the same problem. Please can you give proper solution of that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Going to follow up on the spaCy forums where you asked the same question, instead of here, because it's easier to have extended discussion there. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10402